# A closed form for the following Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

I was computing some calculations, when I got stuck about a possible closed form for this series:

$$S = \sum_{k = 2}^{N}\ \frac{k!}{k^k - k!}$$

I proved by hands that it's absolutely convergent by using the ratio test, but now I have to find something with which to approximate that series, or a closed form if it does exist.

Computing the first $50$ term of the series, the result is around

$$S \approx 1.454864034404(...)$$

If I try to take the limit for large $k$ (namely for large $N$), I can use Stirling approximation

$$k! \approx \sqrt{2\pi k} \frac{k^k}{e^k}$$

I will obtain:

$$S(\text{large}\ k) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi k}}{e^k - \sqrt{2\pi k}}$$

**Numerical evaluation**

"My" alternative form seems good because even for $k = 5$ I got these:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{5!}{5^5 - 5!} & \approx 0.03993 \\\\
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 5}}{e^5 - \sqrt{2\pi 5}} & \approx 0.03924
\end{cases}
$$

Anyway: is there a way to obtain a closed form for a general $N$? I also tried with mathematica but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your last sentence makes me think that there's no close form. Mathematica is usually pretty smart on this kind of things. But I can't tell for 100% of course.

Comment: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc also finds nothing.

Comment: Sophomore's dream might help...

Comment: Even the simpler series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k!}{k^k}$ is not known to possess a closed form. See [OEIS A$94082$](http://oeis.org/A094082).

Comment: @Lucian Indeed! It's so strange! Let's give Mathematica some lesson :D :D

Comment: Could you or other user try with partial summation, I say **Abel summation formula**, with sequence $a_n=1$and for function $f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x^x-\Gamma(x+1)}$? I believe that the first term is a function vanishing when $N\to\infty$ by **Stirling identity**, the second summand is a constant and the third is an integral involving the derivative of **Gamma function**, I don't know how analyze this term, if it is possible, as $\text{a constant+error term}$, with $\text{error term}$ vanishing when $x\to\infty$. I am fllowing your question, thus isn't neccesary a response, thanks